# NavigationITem Centrado IOS SWIFT

Tags: swift, xcode, navigationview

Actualmente a mi Toolbar de iOS necesito dejar un label campo centrado,

Intente con

```
    func setupNavigationBar(showBack:Bool, showMenu:Bool, showFilters: Bool)
    {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

        let sideMenuButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage.init(named: "sideMenu"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(sideMenuPressed))
        sideMenuButtonItem.tintColor = UIColor.black

        let backMenuButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage.init(named: "backButton"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(backPressed))
        backMenuButtonItem.tintColor = UIColor.black

        if(showBack){
            let titleLabel = UILabel()
            titleLabel.text = self.menuText
            titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
            titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            titleLabel.sizeToFit()


            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [backMenuButtonItem]
            // AGREGO LABEL DEL MEDIO
            let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:250, height:20))
            titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x:25, y:0, width:titleView.frame.width, height:titleView.frame.height)
            titleView.addSubview(titleLabel)
            self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;

        }
        else if(showMenu){
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [sideMenuButtonItem]

        }
}
```

Pero mi Label no queda centrado no sabria exactamente como centrarlo

Un ejemplo de como me quedo ahora [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El "PAGAR" deberia quedar centrado en el medio de la pantalla del toolbar

Comment: haz probado `titleLabel.textAlignment = .center`?

Comment: @BlackSheep lo probare

Comment: ¿Has probado con Constraints?